# Wrap websockets asyncio with synchronous API

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using a python [websockets library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) in order to create a websocket server. My goals is to export a **synchronous** API, as it's going to be used outside of python.

As such, I need, at least at the beginning, `start()` and `stop()` methods. So it seems right to create a websocket server class for that.
Main issue it that the way to create (and start) a server through the library is by `await`ing, and so these methods should encouraged to be `async`, which I try to avoid.

The following code work perfectly when I run the main() function.
When runnig `server = WebsocketServer(); server.start(1234)` through `ipython` shell I can't seem to connect through a client code. What am I missing?

```
class WebsocketServer():

    def __init__(self):
        self._server = None

    def start(self, port):
        start_server = websockets.serve(self._handle_client,
                                        host='localhost',
                                        port=port)
        self._server = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)

    def stop(self):
        if self._server:
            self._server.close()
            self._server = None

    async def _handle_client(self, client, path):
        async for buffer in client:
            await self._handle_buffer(client, buffer)

    async def _handle_buffer(self, client, buffer):
        print(buffer)
        await client.send(buffer)

def main():
    server = WebsocketServer()
    server.start(1234)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

The synchronous interface into the IO loop is via [tasks](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#tasks). Scheduling methods return a future that can be synchronously waited on if needed. The [run an event loop](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#run-an-event-loop) section of the docs features a combo for synchronous shutdown in the bottom.

When running inside an iPython shell, one option is to spawn a daemon background thread for the IO loop and register an [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/atexit.html) callback to synchronously shutdown the IO loop when the shell exits.

Another option is to "borrow" shell's thread once in a while for the IO tasks (only works for short tasks, of cause) using the UI Event Loop integration point described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/eventloops.html) describing how to borrow the shell thread for the IO.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the last line from you main function.

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Nothing happens when the loop is not running. So, the server won't be running unless you run the loop.